# Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have project in React which I am trying to connect with firebase.
I have error `"Command terminated with non-zero exit code1"`
I tried to change predeploy on `"npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint"` it didn't help.

I use yarn (here it is written npm), but I tried to change on yarn - also that didn't help.

How do I can make it work?

Comment: Ok, Open a terminal in the `functions` directory and run `npm run lint`.  what is the output?

Comment: Air-Natalia:functions natalia$ yarn run lint
yarn run v1.9.2
$ eslint .
/bin/sh: eslint: command not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: It's not for yarn right?

Comment: Try `npm install -g eslint`. [ESlint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint)

Comment: eslint is a linter that checks your code before it is deployed for certain errors.

Comment: I use yarn everywhere, is it ok to install npm?

Comment: will it break my dependences?

Comment: No, ESLint is a developer side tool for deployment only.  You could save it to your project using `--save-dev`, but ESLint is a very handy tool that I feel should be global.  There are some very good reasons to `--save-dev` instead, but this is just me.

Comment: ok, one sec I am doing

Comment: Also, at some point you may feel the need to completely remove the `predeploy` script.  You can do that and your error goes away.  However, if you fix the warnings and errors you get from ESLint, then you will have fewer problems.

Comment: bash: npm: command not found, when  I run "npm install -g eslint"

Comment: I have it "Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'"  if I delete predeploy

Comment: Ok, so you will probably need to do a few things, without `npm`, your predeploy script needs to be changed from `npm` to `yarn`.  Also, you will need to install eslint using yarn which (after a web search) looks like :`yarn add eslint --dev`.  Unfortunately, from here I'm not sure how to call eslint using yarn, so I don't know what the new `predeploy` script should be.  [Here is an article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-eslint-webpack-babel/#eslint) that looks promising.

Comment: can you run `firebase --version` from the terminal?

Comment: 4.0.3 version in terminal. Also I tried to wright yarn insted of npm in predeploy. It didn't help

Comment: Damn.  Ok, with a missing module, I would normally run `npm install` and it would install the dependencies from the `package.json`.  My only solution to this is to install `npm`.  I don't know any other way, Sorry.

Comment: Okey. Thank you very much